# Why is there an extra spacing below my header element?

Tags: css, react-redux, row, antd

I'm using ant.design and React/Redux and want to adjust spacing between elements, but extra space gets added around my paragraph and heading tags.

I've looked around for inline and css styling, but I haven't been able to find what code is causing the extra spacing.

```
<Row type="flex" justify="center">
    <Col>
        <h2
        style={{
        textAlign: "center",
            color: GREY_2,
        fontFamily: "Lucida Grande",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 22,
        padding: "0px 0px 0px 0px"
        }}
    >
        Online class through infinity2o
    </h2>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

[image: with orange padding]
[image: full div tag]

I expected a div that has a height of 22px because the font size is 22px, but there is extra spacing around the h2 header and even more spacing below the h2 header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orange bar on the h1 is the bottom margin. If you want that space to go away, do `h1 { margin-bottom: 0; }`.

The blue bar containing the text represents line height. To adjust that, do like `div { line-height: 8px; }`.

Edit: In JSX those properties would be `marginBottom` and `lineHeight`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

H tags typically have default margins without seeing the rest of your css i couldnt know for sure, but would be willing to bet that is your problem.

You could set `margin-bottom: 0` if you dont want it like that.